# Merging string in php 7.4 via .= fails - why?

Tags: php-7.4

I'm building a html page with php. The page sometimes displays an error message on top.
In case of an error, I would do

```
   $main_body = "<html to display error message>";
```

and later I put the rest of the site into the same string:

```
    $main_body .="<main html body of page>";
```

The page works fine all through to php 7.3 but it does not work with php 7.4 - why is that? If I change the .= line to = it works:

```
   $main_body ="<main html body of page>";
```

If there is no error message, then $main_body variable was undefined before I do .=
I thought that might be a problem. But if I do

```
   $main_body = "";
```

at the top it doesn't help.

While I can fix the issue I would still like to know what exactly php 7.4 does not like here. In other occasions, .= still works fine!

Comment: There is something else going on here that you've not spotted, but I'm not sure what - PHP doesn't just silently stop concatenating strings.

Comment: If `$main_body` is undefined before the concatenation you get a waring, but it should still return the correct result. setting `$main = ""` wouldn't help, because it's a different variable ...

Comment: Please create a [mre].